Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 version for Windows 10
I am not able to find where my Microsoft Visual Studio IDE is located after downloading version 2017. How can I resolve this? I see some folders called Microsoft Visual Studio and Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0
I already tried to delete and reinstall it. I checked both my folder where the install added folders (program files, program files x86). I also tried to locate devenv.exe as per what chatgpt had said but I can't seem to locate that.

Hi @Reesh, did you run the vswhere.exe to locate Visual Studio installations on your machine?

The default location of Visual Studio IDE 2017 typically can be found in the following location after installing VS on Windows.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<Edition>

If you can't find the location of Visual Studio 2017 IDE in Program Files (x86) and Program Files folders, please open your VS Installer and go to Installation locations tab to check it.

For more information,please read Install Visual Studio 2017
About where to locate devenv.exe, default location:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<Edition>\Common7\IDE\

Besides, you can run vswhere.exe to locate Visual Studio installations on your machine.
Using vswhere.exe
